# Short, illustrated story about aliens who have enslaved earth and made humans as pets/slaves

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have vague memories of a short story I read from my older brother's collection (it would have to be from a *Heavy Metal* magazine as I remember there was a lot of nudity!)

It was about a slave girl who is a pet/servant to these "grog-like, ape-like" aliens that have enslaved earth's population. I'm guessing she gets involved in a revolt and gets her "master" to sympathize for their cause...things don't go as planned and they're caught!  It doesn't end well for the girl as she ends up on a platter (maybe with an apple in her mouth) and the final line from the strip went something like "Lucinda! How tasty she looks!"

Comment: There are some good details that you remember, can I suggest you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details.